# open a folder from a name in txt file BASH

Tags: bash, directory

I have a text file `fold.txt` that contains one line `fold_nam`:

```
$ cat fold.txt
fold_nam
```

This name in the the text file is an output that was created during a program run of a folder's name that now contains other files that I need to work with.

I am writing a big script and now I need to enter this folder and I need to get the name from the text file. I tried several things but cannot really work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use `cat`:

```
cd $(<fold.txt)
```

Comment: This is not portable to traditional Bourne shell, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the line into a variable: `read -r folder_name < fold.txt`

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do this:

```
cd $(cat fold.txt)
```

or

```
cd `cat fold.txt`
```

Comment: @AdamLiss : Granted; you can (and almost certainly should) use I/O redirection to do this.  What would the downside be to using cat in this way?  Would there be any detrimental side effects?  Does it just not look nice?

Comment: Using `cat` instead of a shell built-in will launch an unnecessary process.